# Rails 5.0.2, Capistrano Stopped Deploying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, web-deployment

I've been successfully deploying with Capistrano for several months. After some updates, it stopped working.

Recently we added Spina CMS but have already deployed a version that is live. We did remove a Capistrano Lock awhile back.

If I run:

```
cap production deploy
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'start' (see --tasks)

Tasks: TOP => production
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I then ran:

```
Daves-MBP-2:enduur dave$ cap production deploy --trace
** Invoke production (first_time)
** Execute production
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
cap aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'start' (see --tasks)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:58:in `[]'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:361:in `[]'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capistrano-3.8.0/lib/capistrano/dsl/task_enhancements.rb:7:in `before'
config/deploy.rb:48:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:205:in `in_namespace'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/dsl_definition.rb:140:in `namespace'
config/deploy.rb:39:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capistrano-3.8.0/lib/capistrano/setup.rb:27:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capistrano-3.8.0/lib/capistrano/setup.rb:27:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capistrano-3.8.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/variables.rb:32:in `untrusted!'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/delegate.rb:83:in `method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capistrano-3.8.0/lib/capistrano/setup.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:152:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capistrano-3.8.0/lib/capistrano/application.rb:14:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capistrano-3.8.0/bin/cap:3:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/cap:23:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => production
```

My Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'



gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.2'

gem 'sqlite3'

group :development do
    gem 'capistrano',         require: false
    gem 'capistrano-rvm',     require: false
    gem 'capistrano-rails',   require: false
    gem 'capistrano-bundler', require: false
    gem 'capistrano3-puma',   require: false
end
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'


gem "font-awesome-rails"

gem 'mail_form'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'globalize', git: 'https://github.com/globalize/globalize'
gem 'spina', git: 'https://github.com/denkGroot/Spina'
gem 'spina-articles', git: 'https://github.com/kinnrot/spina-articles.git'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'fog'
gem 'pg'
gem "wysiwyg-rails"
```

It seems the issue the Puma task inside the Deploy file.

Here is my capfile:

```
# Load DSL and set up stages
require "capistrano/setup"
require "capistrano/deploy"
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/puma'

# Include tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
#
# For documentation on these, see for example:
#
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rvm
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv
#   https://github.com/capistrano/chruby
#   https://github.com/capistrano/bundler
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rails
#   https://github.com/capistrano/passenger
#
# require 'capistrano/rvm'
# require 'capistrano/rbenv'
# require 'capistrano/chruby'
# require 'capistrano/bundler'
# require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
# require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
# require 'capistrano/passenger'

# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

Here is my Deploy file:

```
# config valid only for current version of Capistrano

server 'IP', port: 22, roles: [:web, :app, :db], primary: true


set :application, 'APP'
set :repo_url, 'URL'
set :user,            'XX'
set :puma_threads,    [4, 16]
set :puma_workers,    0

# Don't change these unless you know what you're doing
set :pty,             true
set :use_sudo,        false
set :stage,           :production
set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache
set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
set :ssh_options,     { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) }
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true  # Change to false when not using ActiveRecord

## Defaults:
# set :scm,           :git
# set :branch,        :master
# set :format,        :pretty
# set :log_level,     :debug
# set :keep_releases, 5

## Linked Files & Directories (Default None):
# set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
# set :linked_dirs,  %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

namespace :puma do
  desc 'Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket'
  task :make_dirs do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/sockets -p"
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/pids -p"
    end
  end

  before :start, :make_dirs
end

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision do
    on roles(:app) do
      unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
        puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
        puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
        exit
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Initial Deploy'
  task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      invoke 'puma:restart'
    end
  end

  before :starting,     :check_revision
  after  :finishing,    :compile_assets
  after  :finishing,    :cleanup
  after  :finishing,    :restart
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was a Capistrano-puma issue
https://github.com/seuros/capistrano-puma/issues/213

Changing the require line in my Capfile to the following worked:

```
require 'capistrano/puma'
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma::Workers
```

Answer (score 0):

Cant add this as a comment so apologies for the answer which isn't an answer. I upgraded an app to 5.0.2 today and deployed successfully, looking at other questions on the 'don't know how to build' error, it seems to point at the 'require' lines in the capfile. I would suggest you take a look at that & make sure everything is in order.